# Function call error in Python

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have a 1D array X with both +/- elements. I'm isolating their signs as follows:

```
idxN, idxP = X<0, X>=0
```

Now I want to create an array whose value depends on the sign of X. I was trying to compute this but it gives the captioned syntax error.

```
y(idxN) = [math.log(1+np.exp(x)) for x in X(idxN)]
y(idxP) = X(idxP)+[math.log(np.exp(-x)+1) for x in X(idxP)];
```

Is the LHS assignment the culprit?

Thanks.

[Edit] The full code is as follows:

```
y = np.zeros(X.shape)
idxN, idxP = X<0, X>=0
y(idxN) = [math.log(1+np.exp(x)) for x in X(idxN)]
y(idxP) = X(idxP)+[math.log(np.exp(-x)+1) for x in X(idxP)];
return y
```

The traceback is:

```
y(idxN) = [math.log(1+np.exp(x)) for x in X(idxN)]
  File "<ipython-input-63-9a4488f04660>", line 1
    y(idxN) = [math.log(1+np.exp(x)) for x in X(idxN)]
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Comment: Add your full code

Comment: Add the full error traceback.

Comment: You cannot assign a value to a function call. If you are trying to do something to the result of a function call, you will have to use a variable like so: `y = myFunction()` `y.performAction()`

Comment: Add this answer to question not here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some programming languages like Matlab, indexes are references with parentheses. In Python, indexes are represented with square brackets.

If I have a list, `mylist = [1,2,3,4]`, I reference elements like this:

```
> mylist[1]
  2
```

Wen you say `y(idxN)`, Python thinks you are trying to pass `idxN` as an argument a function named `y`.

Comment: But even if I change to this

    y[idxN] = [math.log(1+np.exp(x)) for x in X[idxN]]

it still gives an error

Comment: I hope that my answer illuminated why the `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call` error came up

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work like this:

```
y = np.zeros(X.shape)
idxN, idxP = X<0, X>=0
yn,yp,xn,xp = y[idxN], y[idxP],X[idxN],X[idxP]
yn = [math.log(1+np.exp(x)) for x in xn]
yp = xp+[math.log(np.exp(-x)+1) for x in xp];
```

If there is a better way, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Curiously, yn is a list but yp is float64. Is this expected?